# How to set the DueDate to None via Outlook COM API

Tags: powershell, outlook, com-interop, office-automation

I try to set the `DueDate` property of a task in Outlook via PowerShell to `None`.

I use the following code.

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders" -as [type]
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$item = $outlook.Session.GetItemFromID("myvalidentryid")
$item.DueDate = $null
$item.Save()
```

My problem is that it not set the task to `None`, but instead to `30.12.1899`

I also tried to use `[Nullable[DateTime]]$null` instead of `$null` but I get the same results.

Question: How to reset the `DueDate` (or any other Outlook Date) to `None`?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook seems to define `4501/1/1` as `None`.

The following line is required to set the DueDate to `None` in PowerShell.

```
$item.DueDate = Get-Date -Date "4501-01-01 00:00"
```